# Given that at most five of the balls are gold, find the probability that exactly five of the balls are gold.

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I was attempting a problem that involved conditional probability, and I admit, I am completely lost. I've tried to use independent events $\Bbb P(B\cap A) = \Bbb P(A)  \Bbb P(B)$ to solve the problem; however, the answer does not match the correct answer. I've tried various different methods (different values dividing and multiplying) to reverse engineer the answer.

Without further explanation of why I cannot answer this, here's the problem:

> $14$ balls are drawn from the bag with replacement.
>   $4$ Gold Balls
>   $6$ Silver Balls
>   $\Bbb P(Y=5) = 0.207$
>   $\Bbb P(Y\leq 5) = 0.486$
>   Given that at most five of the balls are gold, find the probability that exactly five of the balls are gold. Give the answer correct to two decimal places.
>   Answer: $0.43$

What should I do to approach this problem?

Comment: P(B|A) is not equal to P(A)*P(B)

Comment: sorry it is actually $P(B|A)=\frac{P(B\cap A)}{P(A)}$

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I call the number of gold balls drawn $Y$, then the probability of interest is
\begin{align*}
P(Y = 5|Y\leq 5) &= \frac{P(Y = 5\cap Y \leq 5)}{P(Y \leq 5)} \\
&= \frac{P(Y = 5)}{P(Y\leq 5)}\\
&=\frac{\binom{14}{5}(4/10)^5(6/10)^9}{\sum_{k = 0}^5\binom{14}{k}(4/10)^k(6/10)^{14-k}}\tag 1\\
&\approx\frac{0.207}{0.486}\tag 2\\
&\approx .43
\end{align*}
where in $(1)$ the denominator and numerator follow a Binomial distribution $n = 14, p = 4/10$, and in $(2)$ I used the approximations given.

Comment: Why does P(Y=5∩Y≤5)/P(Y≤5) = P(Y=5)/P(Y≤5) ?

Comment: What is the intersection of $\{5\}$ and $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$?

Comment: Would the intersection be Y = 5 due to that being the only value in both list 1 and 2 that align with each other?

Comment: Yes, and hence $P(Y = 5\cap Y\leq 5) = P(Y = 5)$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: No problem. Good luck!